# Nginx+apache troubles

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web, nginx

Ubuntu 12.04 x64, DigitalOcean.
I've install nginx+Apache+PHP, but static content not load, urls broken.

[image]
You can see, what proxy_pass set in all urls. If i turn off nginx and change port Apache works fine. 
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
error_log /home/project/logs/nginx.error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_comp_level 7; #Level Compress
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     gzip_http_version 1.1;
     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascri$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project.ru

```
upstream project {
    server 127.0.0.1:81;
}
server {
    listen          80;
    error_page      404     /404.html;
    error_page      403     /403.html;
    server_name     project.ru www.project.ru;

    access_log      /home/project/logs/nginx.access.log;
    error_log       /home/project/logs/nginx.error.log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://project;
    }
    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|mov|avi|mp4|mpeg4) {
            root /home/project/www;
    }

    location ~ /.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: The titles says it all. Why do you want to install 2 kinds of webservers?

Answer (score 0):

With `location / {}` you are passing all requests to the upstream. Move the other location block up or do something like this:

```
location / {
    root /home/project/www;
    try_files $uri @dynamic;
}

location @dynamic {
    proxy_pass http://project;
}
```

> try_files
>   Checks for the existence of files in order, and returns the first file that is found. A trailing slash indicates a directory - $uri /. In the event that no file is found, an internal redirect to the last parameter is invoked. Do note that only the last parameter causes an internal redirect, former ones just sets the internal URI pointer. The last parameter is the fallback URI and *must* exist, or else an internal error will be raised. Named locations can be used. Unlike with rewrite, $args are not automatically preserved if the fallback is not a named location. If you need args preserved, you must do so explicitly.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files